# How to say "the word as a weapon"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

As the titles implies, I wish to know how "The word as a weapon" translates into Latin. I think it would be a cool name for a debate club that I'm setting up.

Answer (score 3):

There are several translations for 'spoken word.' 
*Vox,* meaning 'voice,' is tidy.

'As' could be *quasi* or *tanquam;* *tanquam* is stronger.

*Telum* is the general word for 'offensive weapon,'

> *Vox quasi telum.*

Answer (score 1):

One option is

> verbum sicut arma

*[Arma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arma#Noun_9)* meaning weapon is from late Latin, but I think it makes more sense to the modern reader than *telum*, the word used in Classical Latin.

Comment: @Hugh Oh, I see. I thought accusative was appropriate.

Comment: Could be; but in mottoes almost always Nominative.